# Working Thread Example for android-json-rpc Library

Tags: android, json-rpc

I need a working JSONRPCThreadedClient example for android-json-rpc library. I am currently using 0.3.4.

I have looked at the source code, and I am somewhat confused as to why the create() method in JSONRPCThreadedClient returns a JSONRPCHttpClient instead of a JSONRPCThreadedHttpClient. I have manually edited the code so that it does return a JSONRPCThreadedHttpClient, however because it is in a seperate thread it requires a handler.

I'm not sure how to call the rpc methods and retrieve the result using the required handler... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A Handler will receive messages (handleMessage) in the UI Thread, you cannot do network operations on that Thread, so you HttpClient probably uses a Thread internally and expose only results trough Handlers, you should create one to receive events.